nlme crossed random effects and autoregressive covariance structure
I would like to ask you two specific questions regarding a model in which crossed random effects and autoregressive covariance structure (AR1 -->
therefore use the package nlme instead of lme4) are to be considered. This is based on a 16-week feeding trial (2x2 factorial design) with 32 cows and 16 measurement points (weekly measurement interval) per cow.

How can two non-nested random effects (in lme4: + (1|animal) + (1|experimental_week )) in nlme?

As random = list(one1 = pdMat (~ animal - 1), one2 = pdMat (~ experimental_week - 1)), where one1 and one2 are "auxiliary" variables that are 1 (for each observation) ? Source: r - Modeling random structure in lmer and nlme:lme - Cross Validated (stackexchange.com)
Or else: random = list(animal = pdMat (~1), experimental_week = pdMat (~1)) ?
Or else?
Whereby the correct pdMat object (pdDiag, pdIdent, ...) would have to be selected.


How to correctly account for the autoregressive covariance structure?

correlation = corAR1(0.99, form = ~ 1)
Or correlation = corAR1(form = ~ experimental_week |animal)



At the moment I have it like this:
new_model_1 <- lme(
  fixed = ECM ~ Index, 
  random = list(Animal = pdDiag(~Animal), experimental_week = pdDiag(~experimental_week)),
  data = data1,
  correlation = corAR1(0.99, form = ~ 1), na.action = na.omit)
summary(glht(new_model_1,test = adjusted("BH")))


For the first question, does this answer from Ben Bolker help? In lme, you need to specify crossed random effects in "roundabout" way.

You probably shouldn't be treating experimental_week as a random effect, with its enforced Gaussian distribution of the associated random intercepts. This type of situation is better handled by explicit, flexible modeling of the time variable (experimental_week, here) as a fixed effect. A regression spline can be a good choice.
With this set of data you could also consider a generalized least squares model, which allows for a variety of covariance structures and is also available in the R nlme package. That provides marginal rather than conditional estimates of the fixed-effect coefficients. Frank Harrell discusses modeling this type of longitudinal data in Chapter 7 of Regression Modeling Strategies, including ways to handle the modeling of time.

Thank you very much for your answer! We were not interested in differences between experimental weeks but in differences between feeding groups within the week. We defined Indexes between the feeding groups for each experimental week. Therefore the "experimental_week = pdDiag(~experimental_week)" could be deleted in the model?

@Julia I see no reason to use experimental_week as a random term in this situation. If you agree, that term can be deleted. You should, however, then include experimental_week in some way as a fixed-effect term in the model, even if you aren't interested in differences among weeks per se. Think of it as a covariate that needs to be accounted for so that you can get better estimates of what you care about. Modeling experimental_week as a regression spline would be one good way to do that. See the Harrell reference linked in the answer.
